# using methods of other classes to "overwrite" variables

Tags: java

i'm relativly new to java and experimantating a bit with javafx

i want to change a variable from class A while using a method from class B

Main: thats the main class, it contains all the needed stuff(shows the primaryStage etc) it does have an constructor, so its **not** creating an actual "main-object"

```
public class Main extends Application {
Sub sub = new Sub();
int a;

// stuff

public void aMethod() {
sub.subMethod();
}

}
```

Sub: this class solely surpose is to change the variable a, it does not contain a constructor to create a "sub-object"

```
public class Sub {
//stuff

subMethod(){
int a = 5;
}
```

if i put the line `Main main;` in the Sub class, the program will give me a nullpointer exception, if i'm calling the subMethod(). 
ok...i guess cause i didnt actually create the main object... so far so good.

BUT... if i put in the line `Main main = new Main();` the program wont even start giving me an "exception while running application" error

the strange thing though is, if i put the line `Main main = new Main();` in the subMethod...

```
subMethod(){
Main main = new Main();
int a = 5;
}
```

...the damn thing actually works...(well its slow, guess because with every calling of the method its creating a new object)

why is that so?

and how is it done correctly? :)
(using methods of other classes to "overwrite" variables)

regards
Red

Comment: it doesn't actually work it just compiles the number you set to 5 isn't the same one as the one in the `Main` class. Also the `Main` you are using in the method isn't the same instance as the other one either.

Comment: Could you provide the _entire_ source of your program?  It's really unclear right now.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create more than one instance of `Main` in your program. Probably `Main` is not the best place to store mutable state (class members), but if you want that, you need to pass the instance of `Main` to `subMethod` (and make `a` public, or provide a public setter method):

```
public class Main extends Application {
Sub sub = new Sub();
public int a;

// stuff

public void aMethod() {
sub.subMethod(this);
}

}

public class Sub {
//stuff

subMethod(Main main){
main.a = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want a method to change the value of another class's fields. There are a few ways to do this. If you have  this class

```
public Class A {
   private int a;
   ...

   public void setA(int a) {
      this.a = a;
   }
}
```

You can do something like this

```
public Class B {
   private static A instance;

   ....

   public static void setA(int a) {
      instance.setA(a);
   }
}
```

Or you can take the A in as a parameter to the set method

```
 public Class B {
  ...

   public static void setA(A a, int val) {
       a.setA(val);
   }
}
```

If you want direct access to the fields on `A` you have to make them public (this is usually not what you want to do as it gives complete access rather than just giving just the access the other classes require)

```
Public Class A {
  public int a;
  ...
}
```

Then you can do

```
Public Class B {
    ...
    public static void setVal(A a, int val) {
         a.a = val;
     }
}
```

Also if you don't have the method `setA` in `B` as `static` you'll have to call it on an `instance` of `B` like

```
B b = new B();
b.setA(a, val);
```

Where as if it's static you call it on the `class B`

```
B.setA(a, val);
```